# How can I get AWS Instance Tags in user-data?

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, user-data, aws-powershell

I use aws ec2 userdata with windows powershell scripts. I need instance bootstrapping. My idea is:

- EC2 instance tag adds.It's key name "Version", it's value "1.0.0.158-branchname"

I have tried to get version tag value in userdata. I checked aws http api. It can't return tags. I wrote simple powershell scripts:

```
$instanceId = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id")
aws ec2 describe-tags --filters $filter --query 'Tags[*]'
```

I can get instance Id with aws http api. I can't get instance tags because AWS ec2 userdata can't start "aws.exe".

This script is correct - it is manually run before the instance is started.

Note: "aws" is "aws.exe" (https://aws.amazon.com/cli/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I resolve it, my problem is using aws cli . I use powershell api and fix it.

```
$instanceId = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id")
$versionTag =  Get-EC2Tag | ` Where-Object {$_.ResourceId -eq $instanceId -and $_.Key -eq 'Version'}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just some clarifications as I was facing similar issue..

If the Instance has an IAM role with EC2 Read access..

```
# My need to use AWSDefaults cmdlet to get temp credentials from STS
Initialize-AWSDefaults
$instanceId = irm -uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/metadata/instance-id
$instance = (Get-Instance -InstanceId $instanceId).Instances[0]
$instanceName = ($instance.Tags | ? { $_.Key -eq "Name"} | select -expand Value)
```